# Windbg breakpoint counter

Tags: windbg

I set the following breakpoint:

```
bp MSPTLS!LsCreateLine 100
```

The program crashes before the break point is hit 100 times. When I do `bl` after the crash, I get the following:

```
0 e 5dca4b62     0072 (0100)  0:**** MSPTLS!LsCreateLine
```

I am assuming from this information that the break point was hit 72 times before the crash.

However, when I do `bp MSPTLS!LsCreateLine 80` I am able to hit the breakpoint before the crash telling me that the break point was hit more than 72 times before the crash. Does this 72 not indicate how many times the break point was hit?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259132/windbg-figuring-out-how-many-times-a-breakpoint-was-hit-before-a-crash

Comment: the syntax is 
[~Thread] bp[ID] [Options] [Address [Passes]] ["CommandString"] 
so if your using a conditional bp (or bu), ensure the count comes before your if statement. Otherwise you get "^ Extra character error in"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0072 (0100)` :

- `0072` - this is the number of passes *remaining* before the breakpoint is hit.
- `(0100)` - this is the original limit passed in.

Note that these are hexidecimal values, so the crash was hit on the 142nd iteration (0x100-0x72).

0x80 is smaller than 142 (0x8E), so it expected that you would hit the breakpoint before the crash with that setting.

Link to documentation: [`bl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538891.aspx)